# Update function in my app doesnt work

Tags: android, database

I have a problem since a few day with the app i'm trying to program.
It is rather simple, when the user click on an imageview, the database must update and set this data as "favorite". 
Here's the code :

**Main activity**

```
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Pref = getSharedPreferences("DoctorGames", MODE_PRIVATE);
    pref = Pref.getString("pref", pref);

    try { try {
            Log.i("TEST0", String.valueOf(ID));

            mDbHelper.open();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tgames WHERE _id = '" + ID + "'; ";
            final Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String prefTEST = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
            Log.i("TEST1", prefTEST + query);

            DataHelper.updateFav(ID, pref, mDbHelper.mDb);

            prefTEST = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));

            cursor.close();
            mDbHelper.close();

            Log.i("TEST2", pref +" " + prefTEST);

    } catch ( CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException i){
        Log.i("TEST", "Second");
    }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.i("TEST", "FIRST");
    };
}
```

**Game Activity**

```
   //Remove from favorite
     favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            pref = "co";
             favorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             co.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             mEditor.putString("pref", pref);
             Log.i("TEST", pref);

         }
     });

    //Add to favorite
    co.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pref = "favorite";
            favorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            co.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mEditor.putString("pref", pref);
            Log.i("TEST", pref);
        }
    });
```

**DataHelper class**

public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NAME = "name";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_PLACE = "place";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN = "agemin";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX = "agemax";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN = "nbremin";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX = "nbremax";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_TYPE = "type";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE = "favorite";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_IMG = "img";

private static final String TABLE_GAMES = "tgames";
boolean exterieur = true;
boolean interieur = false;
boolean co = false;
boolean fav = true;
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static String TAG = "DataHelper";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "games.db";
public static SQLiteDatabase mDB;
private final Context mContext;

File dbFile =new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

public DataHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        //DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().toString();
    }else{
        DB_PATH="/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist){
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    this.close();
    try{
        copyDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase data base created");
    }catch (IOException mIOException){
        //throw new Error("ErroCopyingDatabase");
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    File dbFile =new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte [1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0){
        mOutPut.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutPut.flush();
    mOutPut.close();
    mInput.close();
}

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLiteException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    //mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDB != null;
}

public Cursor selectAll(){
    Cursor cAll = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from tgames", null);
    return cAll;
}


public static Cursor search (String name, boolean place, int agemin, int agemax, int nbremin,
                             int nbremax, String type, String description, boolean favorite){
    //A redefinir selon le critère
    //peut etre une recherche par colonne, si élément est pas null? (mais les critères s'entrecroiseront pas alors)

    String query = "SELECT " +
            TABLE_ROW_ID +", " +
            TABLE_ROW_NAME + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_TYPE + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_IMG +
            " from " +
            TABLE_GAMES + " WHERE " +
            TABLE_ROW_NAME + " = '" + name + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + " = '" + place + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + " = '" + agemin + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + " = '" + agemax + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + " = '" + nbremin + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + " = '" + nbremax + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_TYPE + " = '" + type + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION + " = '" + description + "' or " +
            TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE + " = '" + favorite + "';";


    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}

public static Cursor searchTEST(String name, String place, String agemin, String agemax, String nbremin,
                                String nbremax, String type, String favorite) {

    Cursor c = mDB.query(TABLE_GAMES, new String[]{
                    TABLE_ROW_NAME,
                    TABLE_ROW_PLACE,
                    TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN,
                    TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX,
                    TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN,
                    TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX,
                    TABLE_ROW_TYPE,
                    TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION,
                    TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE},

            TABLE_ROW_NAME + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_PLACE + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_TYPE + " = ? AND " +
                    TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE + " = ?",

            new String[]{name, place, agemin, agemax, nbremin, nbremax, type, favorite},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    return c;
}

//MTHODE TEST RECHERCHE
public static Cursor searchNAME(String name){
    String query = "SELECT " +
            TABLE_ROW_NAME + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_TYPE + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION + ", " +
            TABLE_ROW_FAVORITE +
            " from " +
            TABLE_GAMES + " WHERE " +
            TABLE_ROW_NAME + " = '" + name + "';";

    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;

}

//Update FAVORI
public static void updateFav(int id, String fav, SQLiteDatabase DB){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("favorite", fav);

    String selection = "_id" +" = '" + id + "'";
    //String[]selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};

    DB.update("tgames",
            values,
            selection,
            null);

    Log.i("TEST55", values + selection );
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase mDB) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase mDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion)  {

}

 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: can you post your whole dbhelper class?

Comment: Done ! (I edited my post)

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE function is not in a transaction, therefore the change is being rolled back at `db.close()`. try this...

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction()

...insert, update, delete, etc

if (ok) {
   db.setTransactionSucessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. (I use begin.transaction() directly int my updateFav function).
Thank you btw :)

Comment: yw...but you will have to be in a transaction and COMMIT it if you want the UPDATE to "stick". good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your update method is like

```
public static void updateFav
```

Although you made this method static, your databasehelper class holding reference to object while the method is static.

Please make it like this

```
public void updateFav(args..){}
```

and use it as

```
mhelper.updateFav(args);
```

It should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was a nice idea, but it didn't work. I did exactly as you told.